# Accessing variables local to chunk

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on a knitr hook that converts certain objects of a particular class to a polymer tag that will be knitted into html. I am confused on how to access variables that are local to the current chunk. Is there a way to differentiate between variables that are in the global environment and those that are in the chunk that calls the hook?.

```
chart <- function(before, options, envir) {
  if (!before) {
    charts <- lapply(ls(envir), function(obj){
      chart_obj <- eval(parse(text=obj))
      if (is(chart_obj,"FooChart")){
        chart_obj
      }
    })

    ...

  }
}
```

I wrote this thinking envir is the environment that is contained within the chunk. But instead, my current implementation is iterating through the same charts in the global environment from previous chunks.

My goal is to have a chunk like:

````
`r chart=TRUE` 
chart_1 <- app$plot(...)
```
````

and have the hook search the chunk for chart objects to process without searching the global environment.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, variables are not local to chunks: any variable created in a chunk is global.

Comment: @neilfws is right:  you should think of R code in chunks as being executed at the top level, in sequence from first chunk to last.  This isn't exactly true, but `knitr` tries to make it look as if the code is being executed that way.  `knitr` also allows other languages besides R; for (some of?) them, each chunk is evaluated in a separate session.